# Facebook publish_actions usage

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im pretty confused with how i need to approach this issue.

I have a website using a 3rd party app which allowed the admin user to login, type in some content which then appeared on his site aswell as publishing to his FB page. All was working until FB changed their procedures last year (believe it was using the Graph API). Unfortunately the 3rd party no longer support this app so i am trying to see if i can resolve.

The application as far as i can tell uses 3 permissions,

```
manage_pages, publish_actions, publish_pages
```

1. Some threads indicate, i need to complete an App Review which once authorised would get everything working as it should. This is in process to save me some time.
2. Other threads indicate, public_actions is deprecated and cant be used any futher. If i go to FB help pages (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions/#reference-publish_actions) it doesnt list it. In which case i feel this app would therefore no longer work until i fix this AFTER having the app reviewed and accepted?

Can anyone advise which is true and if #2, what do i need to do to get publish_actions to working in this scenario?
Is it possible to have this working in a test enviroment as theres too many variables for me to tackle here i.e. FB state unless the site is https it wont work, app review etc

Answer (score 0):

`publish_actions` does not exist any more, it has been removed.

Posting to user profiles via API is therefor not possible any more.

To post to a page you are an admin of you don’t need that one to begin with though, the appropriate permission for that is `publish_pages`, and that still exists.

Comment: So if i want to test posting to a page, could i do this without having to wait for FB to authorise the app?

Comment: As long as your app is in dev mode, and you test with a user that has a role in the app and admin access to the page, yes.

Comment: I believe i have set it as test now (before i had the app but this time i saw "Create test app" which copied my original app giving different values. When i try to use just the two permissions i get this when i post {
   "error": {
      "message": "The url you supplied is invalid",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 1500,
      "error_subcode": 1611248,
      "is_transient": false,
      "error_user_title": "Invalid URL",
      "error_user_msg": "Failed to parse URL",
      "fbtrace_id": "HOHODEde"
   }
} - searched around but i dont know which URL its referring to?

Comment: BTW I'm testing this locally and have added localhost to app domains and other areas where it asks for a domain

Comment: What exactly are you doing, trying to share a link?

Comment: Yes, i have a FB page and trying to get the closest functionality i used to have which is trying to share a link from my site to a FB page

Comment: So what parameters are you using?

Comment: If i've understood your question, then the URL which im posting to causing the above error is https://graph.facebook.com/[FBPageID]/feed?method=POST&link=[MySiteLink]&format=json&access_token=ABC123 If i can get a working link then i can debug the code to see whats going wrong where

Comment: No, I mean what you passed as the actual value of the `link` parameter.

Comment: localhost URLs do not work well for sharing. Facebook has no way to connect to your localhost to try and extract OG meta data.

Comment: Im using a localhost link to test locally before transferring to a public domain. I will change the link to see if that helps. The link posted within the [MySiteLink] param from above is simple http://localhost:12345/test/ and the encoded URL is http%3a%2f%2flocalhost%3a12345%2ftest%2f (which is what is being sent)

Comment: Looks like changing the link resolved the issue. Let me do a few more tests and if this works, if you could add this to the answer i will accept - thanks